# birds often chirped in the tree /chirped in it / chirped there

Tags: phrase-choice

If I don't want to repeat "the tree" at the end of the sentence which version sound idiomatic or are both versions fine?

> There were many apples on the tree and some birds often chirped **in it**.
>
> There were many apples on the tree and some birds often chirped **there**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'There' in this context is a bit vague - it could refer to the general area around the tree.

'In it' works but feels a bit clunky when used with 'chirped'.

Personally I would go with 'some birds chirped **from** it'.

It's a slightly more pleasant turn of phrase. There is probably an academic explanation for this, but I'm just a native speaker who hasn't studied the language beyond high school, so I hope this explanation is enough.

Answer (score 0):

You could rephrase the whole sentence

> Some birds often chirped in the apple tree which had/bore a lot of fruit.